# A query where the entity name is a variable

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework 6 , is there any possibility to create a query where the entity name is a variable ?
For example :

```
Dim Ename as string
.....
....
Dim query= From t in context.[Ename] where "condition" select t
```

Is this possible ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the way it's usually done, but you could use

```
myDbContext.Set(Type.GetType("Ename"))
    .SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Enames WHERE property = @p0", propertyValue");
```

**See**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544%28v=vs.113%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I've already tried this , but I get an error that "Where " is not a method that exist for DBSET.

Comment: ah shoot, it's not generic, so the rest of your query would have to be text as well... (see edit)

Comment: sorry , can you continue your code with an example how can I read some records with specific conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use this third-party library where you could write queries like this:

```
myDbContext.Set(Type.GetType("Ename"))
    .Where("condition");
```

**See**

https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library